# Is there an isAlpha function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, alpha, isnumeric

I have a variable to hold an id

```vb
Dim empId as String
```

So the format for a valid ID is:

```vb
'the first character should be a letter [A-Z]
'the rest of the string are digits e.g M2895 would be a valid id
```

I would like to check each of those characters to see if they fit the correct `ID`

So far, I have come across the `isNumeric()` function. Is there a similar function in VB.NET to check if a character is a string or alpha character?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Char.IsLetter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`RegularExpressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of checking each character of your string by hand:

```
Dim empId as String = "M2895"
If Regex.IsMatch(empId, "^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]+$") Then
    Console.WriteLine("Is valid ID")
End If
```

If you need a function `isAlpha` you can create this function by using `RegularExpressions` too:

```
Private Function isAlpha(ByVal letterChar As String) As Boolean
    Return Regex.IsMatch(letterChar, "^[A-Z]{1}$")
End Function
```

For completion, to support estonian alphabet too, you can use the following:

```
Dim empId as String = "Š2859"
If Regex.IsMatch(empId, "^[^\W\d_]{1}[0-9]+$") Then
    Console.WriteLine("Is valid ID")
End If
```

Comment: Magic my guy. Thanks. How about if i want to accept lowercase chars?

Comment: replace `[A-Z]` with `[A-Za-z]`. You can use https://www.regexpal.com/ for example to test regular expression. There is also a little cheat sheet for the basics.

Comment: In our (estonian) alphabet, order of letters is 'abc...szš...äöü' - [a-z] doesn't seem best idea here :(

Comment: @Arvo - you only have to change the regex. For estonian alphabet the regex solution should also be possible (see the update).

Comment: I just meant that such kind of regex is not universal solution. For digits and specifc words/phrases - yes; for checking single characters - not always.

Answer (score 4):

You can use functions which works for all Unicode characters

[Char.IsLetter Method (String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zff1at55(v=vs.110).aspx)
*Indicates whether the character at the specified position in a specified string is categorized as a Unicode letter.*

[Char.IsDigit Method (Char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)
*Indicates whether the specified Unicode character is categorized as a decimal digit.*

So you end up with validation like

```
Public Function IsValid(id As String)
    If Char.IsLetter(id, 0) = False Then
        Return False
    End If

    If id.Skip(1).All(Char.IsDigit) = False Then
        Return False
    End If   

    Return True   
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take an isAlpha function, answering the title of this question:

```
Public Shared Function isAlpha(ByVal s as String) as Boolean
    if s is Nothing then return False
    For Each c As Char in s
        If not Char.IsLetter(c) then return False
    Next
    return True
End Function
```

However, to answer the body of the question, here is my mod of @Fabio's answer:

```
Public Function isMyAlphaCode(id As String) as Boolean
    if id is Nothing then return False
    if id.length < 2 then return False
    If Char.IsLetter(id, 0) Then
        Return False
    End If

    If id.Skip(1).All(Char.IsDigit) Then
        Return False
    End If   

    Return True   
End Function
```

Comment: What about the digits part?

Comment: Good point, I answered the title, not the body of the question. I'll update my note accordingly.